# Convert a multi user single company application to a multi company multi user application

Tags: git, web-applications, multi-user

I have a web application that is multiuser but limited to 1 instance (company) per time. What would be the best approach to convert it to a multi company application?

I have thought of the following options:

1. Have a separate database and web server folder for every company,
   but this would make maintenance and updates extremely difficult.
2. Edit the code and when a user will log in, save a company ID bound
   to the user. For every update or insert add an extra column to every
   database table and store this ID in it so that I can separate data
   based on companies. This is quite a tedious job but should pay off well
3. Use GIT to handle the different installations in step 1 by forking them, but this
   would still leave me with the issue of replicating changes done to
   the production database to all the other instances.
4. Have a different schema in the same database for every company using
   it.

Are there any tools available to overcome this sort of problem?

Answer (score 1):

I would do a version of option 2, but instead of adding a company ID column to every table, just add it to the user table. Then you can tie any table that has a user ID column to the company ID. Granted, you will have to add a company ID column to any table that has company-specific data but not a user ID.